# how a monorepo packages share one type declaration file?

Tags: typescript

```
└── packages
    ├── foo
    └── bar
|___typings.d.ts
```

I have a project structure like this, I don't want to repeat `typings.d.ts` in every package, so I want to move it at root

I have already `include` the `typings.d.ts` in packages' `tsconfig.json`

```json
// packages/foo/tsconfig.json
{
 include:["../../typings.d.ts"]
}
```

but the types in Window can't be find

```
// typings.d.ts

interface Window{
    foo:string;

}
```

`window.foo` will emit a type error